# What does this DNS record mean?

Tags: dns

I have this DNS record in my domains's zone file:

```
TXT cmaflooring.com v=spf1 a mx include:websitewelcome.com ~all Automatic
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Added formatting fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an SPF record.  The following website from OpenSPF[1] has a good explanation.

1. http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax